# How to use abstract multi methods containing a where?

Tags: oop, abstract-class, where-clause, abstract, raku

I'm working on a Perl 6 module, [`Pod::To::Anything`](https://gitlab.com/tyil/perl6-pod-to-anything), in an effort to make an easy interface to create Perl 6 Pod formatters. I'm splitting up rendering into multiple `render` methods, each having to deal with a given part of [the Pod specification](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pod).

To ensure the Pod formatters based on this class are complete, I want to add in abstract methods that cover all the possible Pod objects. However, this requires me to use a `where` clause a couple of times:

```
multi method render (Pod::Block::Named:D $ where *.name eq "NAME" --> Str) { … }
```

I've tried to implement it as follows:

```
multi method render (Pod::Block::Named:D $pod where *.name eq "NAME" --> Str) { ".TH {self.pod-contents($pod)}\n" }
```

However, when I try to run the program, Perl 6 complains about a method not being implemented:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/tyil/projects/personal/perl6-Pod-To-Man/lib/Pod/To/Man.pm6 (Pod::To::Man)
Multi method 'render' with signature :(Pod::To::Man $: Pod::Block::Named:D $ where { ... }, *%_ --> Str) must be implemented by Pod::To::Man because it is required by a role at /home/tyil/projects/personal/perl6-Pod-To-Man/lib/Pod/To/Man.pm6 (Pod::To::Man):7
```

It's LTA that Perl 6 hides the actual contents of the `where` part here, but that is not my main issue. The issue I have is that it tells me a method I did implement is not implemented.

I've golfed it down a little to ensure this is not a specific problem to my current codebase:

```
role Foo { multi method test(%foo where *<bar>) { … } }
class Bar does Foo { multi method test(%foo where *<bar>) { "Implementation" } }
```

This code errors with a similar error:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /tmp/tmp.o2aoet3JrE/t.pl6
Multi method 'test' with signature :(Bar $: %foo where { ... }, *%_) must be implemented by Bar because it is required by a role
at /tmp/tmp.o2aoet3JrE/t.pl6:5
```

My question becomes: How can I use abstract multi methods containing a `where` clause in Perl 6?

Comment: Boy, yet another long journey with my answer. I think it's now actually correct. But then again I thought that when I first wrote it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** The issues here relate to the fundamental nature of `where` clauses and P6. Rakudo's error message is [LTA](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-LTA). You can use `where` clauses but you'll have to change how you're using them.

## `where` clauses and separate compilation of modules

P6 compiles modules. It does not store source code in the modules, including the source code of the `where` clause. So when it goes to compare the `where` clause in a user's source file that `use`s the module containing the `role`, with the `where` clause in the role, it can't know they're the same so it conservatively decides it can't accept it.

## LTA error message

As explained, the compiler does not store the source code in the compiled module. So that's why it's showing `where { ... }`.

What it could do is produce an awesome "you can't do that", perhaps with the actual `where` clause source code, when compiling the role rather than waiting to inevitably fail when compiling the class doing the role.

I've searched rt.perl.org and the github rakudo repo issues and have not found a corresponding ticket. So I've opened [#2146](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2146).

## P6's nominal type dispatch supports use of `subset`s

Routine dispatch is primarily driven by nominal (named) types.

By declaring a `subset` you can give a `where` constraint a name which you can then plug into signatures thus enabling routine dispatch to do as you wish:

```
subset Nominal-Type where *.key eq 'bar';
role Foo { multi method test(Nominal-Type $baz) { … } }
class Bar does Foo { multi method test(Nominal-Type $baz) { "Implementation" } }

Bar.new.test: my Nominal-Type $baz = :bar
```

## Subsets and sigils

It's important to note that there's [an aged bug](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131381) that means subsets do not work with variables declared with the explicitly composite sigils (`%` and `@`).

So you *must* either use the scalar sigil `$` or slash the sigil.

This requirement applies both to the signatures of the abstract methods you write in your roles and to the signatures of the concrete methods your users write.

## Composite subsets

You *can* write composite subsets. The example above is a scalar subset, but you could write, say:

```
subset Nominal-Type-Hash of Hash where *<bar>;
role Foo { multi method test(Nominal-Type-Hash \qux) { … } }
class Bar does Foo { multi method test(Nominal-Type-Hash \qux) { "Implementation" } }

Bar.new.test: my %baz := my Nominal-Type-Hash \qux = { :bar }
```

Note that I've switched to slashing the sigil in the declaration with the subset type. This is because those using your subset may wish to bind to a new variable with a sigil, as I did in the last line and they might in the body of their methods.

Slashing the sigil instead of using `$` ensures that a sigil'd alias is clearly distinct. Users can't, for example, accidentally write the `$` sigil'd version of the variable name when they meant to write the `%` sigil'd version. Change the name too for extra safety points:

```
class Bar does Foo { multi method test(Nominal-Type-Hash \qux) { my %baz := qux; # use %baz from here on... } }
```

## A subset for your use case

So, you can subset an existing nominal type to create a new nominal type that has a distinct name from the existing type and you can (usually will) add a `where` clause to that new type:

```
subset PTA-BN of Pod::Block::Named where *.name eq "NAME"
```

Now code can use `PTA-BN` (or whatever name you choose) as the parameter type constraint. (I think that'll be simpler and less error prone for your users than copying the `where` clause anyway.)

## Exporting your subset

Per our discussion in comments below, you'll need to add an `is export` to your subsets:

```
subset PTA-BN is export of Pod::Block::Named where ...
```

and also a custom EXPORT routine (`sub EXPORT { { PTA-BN => PTA-BN } }`) as explained [here](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#index-entry-sub_EXPORT).

## Subsets of subsets

You can build up subsets of subsets of subsets etc:

```
subset PTA-BN2 of PTA-BN where some-other-condition;
```

which would ensure that not only is the underlying type of the value at run-time `Pod::Block::Named` *and* its name "NAME" but *also* that `some-other-condition` is true too.

I mention this mainly as a nice prelude to ...

## User defined `where` clauses

While routine dispatch is *primarily* driven by nominal (named) types, necessitating the rest of this answer, there is an exception and it actually involves `where` clauses!

Routine dispatch pays attention to a `where` clause on a parameter inasmuch as any such clause is considered epsilon (a tiny bit) narrower than not having a clause.

In your original code the corresponding parameter of the role and class methods both had a `where` clause so that doesn't apply. cf [Signature Introspection](http://design.perl6.org/S06.html#Signature_Introspection).

But this feature enables a nice little twist in your use case. Implementing methods can combine the subset that your role provides written on the left of a parameter with a `where` clause the user writes on the right and they will get dibs on matching:

```
use Your::Module;
class User's-Class does your-role;
multi method render (PTA-BN $pod where foo --> Str) { ... } # first dibs
multi method render (PTA-BN $pod where bar --> Str) { ... } # second dibs
multi method render (PTA-BN $pod --> Str) { ... } # default
```

Comment: Could I do it as `subset Pod::Block::Named::Name is export of Pod::Block::Named where *.name eq "NAME`, and export it from the same file that holds the `Pod::To::Anything` class unit? I'd preferably have end-users (and myself) only need 1 `use` statement to get started with using this entire construct.

Comment: If I add that `subset` code above the `unit role Pod::To::Anything;` code, I get `Invalid typename 'Pod::To::Anything'` from the module trying to use it (specifically on the line calling `unit class Pod::To::Man does Pod::To::Anything;`). If I put the `subset` after that line, I get `Cannot declare our-scoped subset inside of a role`.

Comment: Hi @Tyil. Please note that I've substantially updated my answer with the most important bit for your attention being that you can not use the `%` or `@a` sigils in a signature with a subset. (You can rebind to one in the body. I mention that too.) I'd also really like to know if my export solution worked for you. If not, I can try work on that. I hope to read a comment from you when you have time. TIA.

Comment: Hi @raiph. Your solution has worked for me, and your extensive answer has really helped a lot. I had accepted your answer once I got my issue fixed. I'd like to thank you for your contributions in SO and reddit threads, as you always seem to go the extra mile to help people out. I had never worked with `EXPORT` before, so I had to read up a bit on that, but it is working as intended for `Pod::To::Anything` and `Pod::To::Man` right now. Again, thanks a lot!